# SceneKit – pan gesture is moving node too quickly

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm currently trying to use a pan gesture recognizer to move a node in SceneKit. I'm only moving it along the `X`-axis, however my gesture moves the object a lot further/faster then it should even when only using small gestures. I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong here but here's the code for my gesture recognizer:

```
@objc func handlePan(_ pan:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if pan.state == .changed {
        let translation = pan.translation(in: pan.view!)

        node!.position = SCNVector3(x:node!.position.x + Float(translation.x), y:node!.position.y, z:node!.position.z)      
        pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: pan.view!)
    } 
}
```

As I say the object is being moved it's just being launched at incredible speed and distance. The effect almost appears cumulative.

I thought this could be the case if I didn't reset the translation of my pan gesture recognizer, but I am doing that here

```
pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: pan.view!)
```

I'm actually trying to get this work in an ARKit scenario, but I've stripped all that out to just get a node moving correctly but I'm still having issues.

The pan is added to an ARSCNView whereas the node I'm trying to manipulate is added as a childNode to the `ARSCNView.scene.rootNode` so I'm wondering if it's the positions/coordinates of these that are the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let translation = pan.translation(in: pan.view!)
```

This code returns CGPoint with gesture position in the view in `points` (which is could be pixels). But SCNNode position (in real world) is position in meters. So, when you're adding one point for `X` position in SCNVector, you're actually adding one meter for that.

To convert screen point into 3D world coordinates use `unprojectPoint` method of `ARSCNView`. You probably will need to save previous gesture position to be able to find position changes.

Comment: Ah right, how do we go about doing the conversion there then? I've mainly worked in SpriteKit which is obviously where I'm trying to convert this code from

Comment: `Z` in `SCNVector` for `unprojectPoint` - is depth, which is could be zero for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a quick play around but my object always moves to the left now regardless of which way I pan but I'll keep trying and look at saving the previous position as you suggest